# How can i delete a session in view in cakephp 2.0?

Tags: cakephp

I have read in the cake book that Session in view uses SessionHelper, but that helper doesn't have method to delete session. Is this really so, could anyone help?

Comment: it seems that it does have delete - http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1316/delete

Comment: Can I ask you why you would need to expire a Session *in a view*? Best practices are that you perform these checks in the controller. That said... a View is just a PHP file, you can always load a class and execute its methods!

Comment: You can use [Shim.Session helper](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/blob/master/src/View/Helper/SessionHelper.php#L45) which contains a consume() one at least (in light of 3.x upgrading).
But either way you should try to prevent deleting in the view layer, this should be done in the controller layer instead.

Answer (score 6):

To [delete session data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#SessionComponent%3a%3adelete), use the [Session Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#sessions) within a Controller, not a View.

```
//example from the CakePHP book (linked above)
$this->Session->delete('Person');
```

Or:

> The destroy method will delete the session cookie and all session data
>   stored in the temporary file system. It will then destroy the PHP
>   session and then create a fresh session:

```
$this->Session->destroy();
```

While it's technically possible to delete session data in a view (it's just a PHP file after all), the CakePHP Framework was built with the MVC structure in mind.  The "V" (for "view") should only be related to displaying the data provided by the Controller (retrieved from the Model).

The Model deals with accessing the data/database, and the Controller does the application logic.  So - the Session Component (components are for controllers) is given a method to delete session data, but the Session Helper (helpers are for views) is not.

Comment: While your answer *is* correct, please take a couple more minutes to tell him why. From his question, he obviously doesn't know ;)

Comment: Oerd: explained in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what is the situation Custom Flash Messages can be used. Set flash message with custom key, like this

`$this->Session->setFlash('my_value', 'default', array(), 'my_key');`

and read it in view using flash method (which will automatically delete it)

`$value = $this->Session->flash('my_key');`

more details in this post http://hashmode.com/cakephp-delete-session-in-view/81

Answer (score 1):

try `unset($_SESSION['YOUR_SESSION_KEY']);` in your view.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a session variable, you can use the following code (**in a Controller**).

```
// same as unset($_SESSION['your_session_varable'])
$this->Session->delete('your_session_varable');
```

You can destroy all session variables calling the following:

```
$this->Session->destroy();
```

Comment: only in controller scope, though!

Answer (score 0):

If the session data is an array and you want to access it just once just like the setFlash, you can set the array to setFlash with no template = false.

```
$this->Session->setFlash($arrayData,false,array(),'formData');
```

And then access it in the view

```
$data = $this->Session->flash('formData');
pr($data);
```